# sorting the Hierarchical table like 1.1.1

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sorting, select, common-table-expression

i am using CTE to manage my hierarchy data. Below is my select query

```
 WITH ctLevel
                AS
                (
                    SELECT
                        C_TASK_ID                                                               AS Child
                        ,P_Task_ID                                                              AS Parent
                        ,common_task.   TASK_SEQ                                                AS taskSeq
                        ,1                                                                      AS [Level]
                        ,CAST( TASK_SEQ AS VARCHAR(MAX))                                        AS [taskOrder]
                        ,CAST (Replicate(TASK_SEQ,  1)+' '+ TASK_NAME  AS VARCHAR(MAX))  AS [Task_Name]
                        ,common_task.TASK_POSITION                                              AS [TASK_POSITION]
                    FROM   
                        [COMMON.TASK_REL] as common_task_rel, 
                        [COMMON.TASK] as common_task
                    WHERE  
                        common_task_rel.C_TASK_ID = common_task.TASK_ID
                        and     common_task.[TASK_TYPE] = 'F' AND common_task.[MODULE_CODE] ='PRODE' AND common_task.[STATUS] <> 'D'
                        and     common_task_rel.P_TASK_ID is null

                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT 
                        C_TASK_ID                                                                   AS Child
                        ,P_Task_ID                                                                  AS Parent
                        ,common_task.   TASK_SEQ                                                    AS taskSeq
                        ,[Level] + 1                                                                AS [Level]
                        ,[taskOrder] + '.' + CAST(TASK_SEQ AS VARCHAR(MAX))                         AS [taskOrder]
                          ,CAST (Replicate('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', [Level] + 1) + taskOrder + '.' + CAST(TASK_SEQ AS VARCHAR(MAX))+' ' +common_task.TASK_NAME AS VARCHAR(MAX))  AS [Task_Name]
                        ,common_task.TASK_POSITION                                              AS [TASK_POSITION]
                    FROM   
                        [COMMON.TASK_REL]as common_task_rel
                    INNER JOIN 
                        ctLevel
                    ON 
                        ( P_Task_ID = Child ) ,
                        [COMMON.TASK] as common_task

                    WHERE  
                            common_task_rel.C_TASK_ID = common_task.TASK_ID
                    and     common_task.[TASK_TYPE] = 'F' AND common_task.[MODULE_CODE] = 'PRODE' AND common_task.[STATUS] <> 'D'
                    )

                   SELECT [Parent] ,[Child],taskSeq, Level,[taskOrder],Task_Name,[TASK_POSITION]
                    FROM   ctLevel  
                    order by [taskOrder],[Level],[TASK_POSITION]
```

How my result look like:

[image]

You may c the example.The
    **10
    10.1
    10.1.1
    10.1.1.1** suppose will be at the bottom of the 9

Is it possible to sort those record like below

```
1
2
2.1
2.2
2.4
2.5
2.6
2.7
3
3.1
3.2
4
4.1
4.2
5
5.1
6
6.1
6.2
6.3
6.4
6.5
7
8
9
9.1
9.1
9.1.1
9.1.1.1
9.1.1.2
9.1.1.3
9.1.1.4

10
10.1
10.1.1
10.1.1.1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: since the data will be treated as text when sorting, you'll need to ensure each section (between your .'s) use the same number of characters.  1 would need to be expressed as 01 in order for your sort to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the numbers like `001`, for example:

```
right('000' + convert(varchar(max), [Level] + 1),3)
```